# Exclude wildcard containing string 'x'

Tags: bash, grep, wildcard

Is there a way to modify `egrep -rha 'part1.*part2'` to add something like: "if `.*` contains (not necessarily equals) `string_x` then pattern is not a match"? The problem is that `string_x` is present in every line so I can't `-v` it. It's okay to have this string before or after pattern, just not in the middle of it.

I'm assuming double `.*` with `not string_x` between them will get the job done, but it'll take a lot of time, plus I sometimes use `.{n,m}` wildcard, and in this case it would double the desired wildcard length. Maybe some sort of search termination every time it encounters `string_x` before part2?

Comment: You can always pipe another grep: `grep 'part1.*part2' | grep -v 'part1.*string_x.*part2'`.

Comment: Wouldn't it take forever? Does `grep -v` only happens when first grep finds a match or all the toime?

Comment: Why forever? it's likely to be the most efficient. The second `grep` will only act on the _output_ of the first `grep`. By the way, there's no way to specify `not string_x` as you mention.

Comment: Because every wildcard seems to double search time which is around 2min without any on them. Will definitely test it. Would it be easier if I were to exclude not string but a single char?

Comment: If you want to exclude a char, it's probably going to be faster: for example if you want to exclude the character `c` between `part1` and `part2`, you can use: `grep 'part1[^c]*part2'`.

Comment: I see that `[^c]` works, but why? I would expect it to say "first leter after part one is not c". Does`[^c]*` mean any combination of letters without `c`? I saw something similar before, iirc it's possible to do logical OR for single chars this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget you ever heard about `-r` or any other option to let `grep` find files. There's a perfectly good tool for finding files with an extremely obvious name - `find`. Keep grep for what it's good at which is doing `g/re/p`. I can't imagine what the GNU guys were smoking when they decided to give grep options to find files, but hopefully they aren't now plotting to add options to sort files or pull content from web sites or print process data or do anything else that existing tools do perfectly well!

In this case you're looking for more than just `g/re/p` though so you should use awk:

```
awk '/part1.*part2/ && !/part1.*string_x.*part2/'
```

So the full script would be something like (untested since no sample input/output provided):

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/part1.*part2/ && !/part1.*string_x.*part2/' {} +
```

Comment: "I can't imagine what the GNU guys were smoking when they decided to give grep options to find files". +1. Major Unix philosophy violation.

Comment: First of all, thank you, this works perfectly.  Although this script takes 2-3 times longer than grep (at least when it comes to searches w/o wildcards). Well, something to learn for me.

Comment: You're welcome. wrt `this script takes 2-3 times longer than grep` - that awk should be faster than 2 greps + a pipe so I find that hard to believe so please post **exactly** the 2 scripts you were comparing as you could be talking about 1 awk vs 1 grep or 1 find+awk vs 1 grep or 1 awk vs 2 greps and you could be using a different regexp in each case or something else and it'd be good to know exactly what the comparison is that's producing that result as I suspect it's not apples-to-apples.